# Zero article with ordinal numbers

Tags: articles, zero-article, ordinals

Recently I've seen several examples of phrases like 'awarded for first place' on Wikipedia etc. (E.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_ribbon)

I think I understand when definite or indefinite articles are used with ordinal numbers, but what does a zero article mean before ordinals? Does it imply that the 'first place' is treated as a mass noun here?.. Is it even correct/grammatical?

Comment: When the ordinal number refers to a place in the results of a race or competition, zero article is usual. _He took second place in the 100 metres_.

Comment: The (optional, usually omitted) article before ***second place*** is usually the *definite* article *(He claimed [the] second place in the race)*. But it's usually the *indefinite* article in contexts like *He is [**a**] second cousin to the Duke of Westminster* (again, usually omitted). That's because there's only usually one second place in a race, but noteworthy relatives usually have *lots* of "second cousins".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's quite correct. Numbers, not just ordinals, often remove the need for an article. For example, you could say "I have *an* apple", or "I have *one* apple". You could say "Astralbee is *the best* at answering English questions" or "is *number one* for answering English questions".

There are plenty of other contexts where you might use an article with an ordinal, for example, "it was *the first place* I visited", but in a race the zero article is idiomatic. A numbered position in a race is something specific, so there isn't a need for a definite article to add specificity.

Comment: What about a phrase like 'the first step in solving any problem is realizing there is one'? It's generally cited on the internet with 'the', but in somewhat famous speech from 'The Newsroom' ('America is not the greatest country in the world anymore') the guy at the end says it without 'the'. How to reason about such phrases?..